# Запись @_(r'\d+') — что значит?

Tags: python

Вообщем в некоторых кодах из интернета нахожу такую вещь.
Что то типо такого:

```
@_(r'\d+')
```

Когда запускаю код с такой штукой, у меня вылазит ошибка. Может кто нибудь объяснить что это такое и как это использовать? Как ошибку убрать

UPDATE:
[image: error]

Comment: Приведите код, который запускаете, и конкретные ошибки в самом вопросе.

Comment: Покажите более крупный кусок кода, где вы это видели. Могу предположить, что это декоратор, например, но нужно смотреть код.

Comment: Вы это нашли здесь? https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sly.html#adding-match-actions

Comment: @wchistow , да, там

Comment: @Rodion Ну вот там же и написано, что это декоратор.

Comment: @CrazyElf тоесть просто так нужен? Почему тогда ошибка?

Comment: @Rodion Какая ошибка, где ошибка? Вы используете ту библиотеку, на которую выше ссылка или просто так пытаетесь такой код в свою программу вставить? Ошибку нужно показывать в прямо вопросе. И код с ошибкой, а не просто кусочек кода.

Comment: Обновил, картинка с ошибкой прикреплена

Comment: И всё же нужно приводить код, где возникла ошибка не куском, а нормальным фрагментом. Если я правильно понял, вы должны использовать эту конструкцию внутри своего класса, унаследованного от Lexer. Вы так и делаете? Без кода приведённого в вопросе это невозможно понять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
@_(r'\d+')
```

Как я и угадал в комментарии, это декоратор.
`@` - используется для обозначения декораторов в Питоне.
`_` - это просто название декоратора, этот символ обычно в Питоне используется для временных переменных, значение которых не важно и им не хотят давать символьное имя. В данном случае авторы библиотеки почему-то назвали так декоратор.
`(r'\d+')` - это аргумент декоратора, в данном случае это регулярное выражение

> The @_() decorator is defined automatically within the Lexer class–you don’t need to do any kind of special import for it.

Декоратор `_` автоматически определяется внутри класса `Lexer`.

Спасибо wchistow за [ссылку](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sly.html#adding-match-actions).

Comment: У меня на неё ошибка, обновил.

Comment: @Rodion вопрос был _что значит эта запись_. На данный вопрос дан отличный ответ. Для решения проблемы с вашей ошибкой лучше создать новый вопрос и прикрепить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve) кода.